# jQuery load() callback fails without alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-callback

I'm loading an html fragment from another page on the site, into a content div. In the load callback, I'm loading JS unique to the new content.

With the `alert()` after `$.getScript`, everything works. Without the `alert()`, `setup()` won't run.

1. I've tried to wait with `setTimeout/clearTimeout`.
2. I've tried calling `$(document).ready` again.
3. I've tried in-lining the new JS (w/o getScript).

No joy. Simplified example below:

```
   <html>
    <head><!-- load jQuery, stylesheets, etc.--> </head>
    <body>

    <div id="menupanel">
        <!-- menu clicks call jQuery: $('#content').ajaxLoad( myURL ). -->
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <!-- Content is inserted here by menu clicks.-->
    </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( function(){

        //Function to load a fragment from another page into this page.
        function ajaxLoad(url,parms){
          var url= url + ' #remoteContent';
          $("#content").load( url, parms, callback(sometext) );
        }

      function callback(sometext) {
        //unbind all events on the #content div. 
        $('#content').off();  

        //run scripts specific to newly loaded page
        //and bind new events to elements on the new page.
        $.getScript('getTest.js',function(){    
          alert('bingo');   //setup() won't run w/o this alert.  
          setup();   
        });
      } 
      //handle menu clicks.
      $("#menu a").click(function(e){
         //etc...
      });

    })  //document ready

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

sample code in **getTest.js**

```
    function setup(){
      var myCount= $("#content").find(".subhead_title").length;

      $("#content #remoteContent #lotPage #lotText").find(".subhead_title").css('color','green');

      console.log('count of subhead titles: '+myCount); 
    }
```

Comment: you need to know the difference between passing a function as an argument, and passing the result of a function as an argument ... `$("#content").load( url, parms, callback() );` should be `$("#content").load( url, parms, callback );`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm actually passing a parameter in the callback, but didn't show that in the edited/shortened code. Fixed now.

Comment: That's the point though: Calling a function with `()`, parameters or not, *executes* the function and passes its result, it does not pass the function itself. If you want to pass params to the function, wrap it in an anonymous function **just like you did with `$.getScript('getTest.js',function(){ `** -- `$("#content").load( url, parms, function() {  callback(someText) });`

Comment: `Sorry for the confusion` - I wasn't confused at all, incorrect code is incorrect, adding a parameter doesn't change how incorrect it is

Comment: BINGO! That was absolutely the issue. Thank you - clearly the confusion was all on my side. Works as designed now.